# Image uploading to SQLite db using Camera but not from Gallery

Tags: android, android-studio, image-uploading

I am new to android programming. I have the code below which adds an image to my `gallery` SQLite database table. This works fine for when I am adding an image using my camera, however, when I select an image from the gallery it seemingly does nothing as no data gets inserted into the table. Any ideas why this may be the case?

```
public class add_gallery extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button addImage;
    //change contact later
    ArrayList<Gall> imageArry = new ArrayList<>();
    //change to GalleryImageAdapter later
    GalleryImageAdapter imageAdapter;
    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1;
    private static final int PICK_FROM_GALLERY = 2;
    ListView dataList;
    //maybe change to image title later
    byte[] imageName;
    int imageId;
    Bitmap theImage;
    DatabaseHelper myDb;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_gallery);
        dataList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        /**
         * create DatabaseHelper object
         */
        myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        /**
         * Reading and getting all records from database
         */
        List<Gall> images = myDb.getAllGallery();
        for (Gall cn : images) {
            String log = "ID:" + cn.getID() + " Image: " + Arrays.toString(cn.getImage())
                    + " ,Title: " + cn.getTitle()
                    + " ,Caption: " + cn.getCaption();

            // Writing Galls to log
            Log.d("Result: ", log);
            // add images data in arrayList
            imageArry.add(cn);

        }
        /**
         * Set Data base Item into listview
         */
        imageAdapter = new GalleryImageAdapter(this, R.layout.gallery_list,
                imageArry);
        dataList.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
        /**
         * go to next activity for detail image
         */
        dataList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                    final int position, long id) {
                imageName = imageArry.get(position).getImage();
                imageId = imageArry.get(position).getID();

                Log.d("Before Send:****", Arrays.toString(imageName) + "-" + imageId);
                // convert byte to bitmap
                ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                        imageName);
                theImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                Intent intent = new Intent(add_gallery.this,
                        DisplayImageActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("imageid", imageId);
                intent.putExtra("imagename", theImage);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
        /**
         * open dialog for choose camera/gallery
         */

        final String[] option = new String[] { "Take from Camera",
                "Select from Gallery" };
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, option);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        builder.setTitle("Select Option");
        builder.setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.e("Selected Item", String.valueOf(which));
                if (which == 0) {
                    callCamera();
                }
                if (which == 1) {
                    callGallery();
                }

            }
        });
        final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

        addImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);

        addImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.show();
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * On activity result
     */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK)
            return;

        switch (requestCode) {
            case CAMERA_REQUEST:

                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();

                if (extras != null) {
                    Bitmap yourImage = extras.getParcelable("data");
                    // convert bitmap to byte
                    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    assert yourImage != null;
                    yourImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                    byte imageInByte[] = stream.toByteArray();
                    Log.e("output before conversion", Arrays.toString(imageInByte));
                    // Inserting Image to gallery
                    Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
                    myDb.addGallery(new Gall(imageInByte,"The Title","The Description"));
                    Intent i = new Intent(add_gallery.this,
                            add_gallery.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();

                }
                break;
            case PICK_FROM_GALLERY:
                Bundle extras2 = data.getExtras();

                if (extras2 != null) {
                    Bitmap yourImage = extras2.getParcelable("data");
                    // convert bitmap to byte
                    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    assert yourImage != null;
                    yourImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                    byte imageInByte[] = stream.toByteArray();
                    Log.e("output before conversion", Arrays.toString(imageInByte));
                    // Inserting Galls
                    Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
                    myDb.addGallery(new Gall(imageInByte, "The Title", "The Description"));
                    Intent i = new Intent(add_gallery.this,
                            add_gallery.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }

                break;
        }
    }

    /**
     * open camera method
     */
    public void callCamera() {
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
                android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);

    }

    /**
     * open gallery method
     */

    public void callGallery() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        intent.putExtra("aspectX", 0);
        intent.putExtra("aspectY", 0);
        intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
        intent.putExtra("outputY", 150);
        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        startActivityForResult(
                Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"),
                PICK_FROM_GALLERY);

    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest saving the image to an external directory and keep in your database only a pointer to that file.  SQLite is not meant to be used as a document database (which is what you do here)

regarding your main question, have you inspected in debug mode what imageInByte is?  It probably is not what you expect, which leads to the blank data inserted to your database

Comment: @BrunoCarrier I see this a lot, unfortunately storing an image as byte array in the db just happens to be a requirement for a university project.

Comment: Oh ok, then by all means go for it :)

have you tried debugging to see what imageInByte is?  I believe it might not contain any data